# moveToThread(qApp->thread()) and signal-slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots

If I understand correctly, slots will always occur in the main thread.
So what is the difference between using the signal-slot system and `moveToThread(qApp->thread())`?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is incorrect.

Each thread has its own event queue, so when a signal is emitted, if the connection is queued (not direct), it will be added to the event queue matching the thread affinity of the object.

For example: -

Let's assume that we have 2 objects; *object1* running on the main thread and *object2*, which has been moved to a new thread.

```
connect(object1, &SomeObject::signal1, object2, &SomeOtherObject::signal2);
```

When *object1* emits *signal1*, an event is posted to the new thread; the thread to which *object2* was moved.

When the new thread processes its event loop and the event for *signal1* it will execute *object2*'s slot, *signal2*. This is not on the main thread.

Comment: thank you so much. I have acouple of questions:
1. what is "thread affinity of the object"? the thread that the object was created in?
2. so if I'm in a worker thread and I want to change the gui, I need to do it from the main thread. I can only use moveToThread() function? what about invokeMethod?

Comment: Thread affinity is the thread on which an object is running. If object2 starts on the main thread, it has thread affinity with that thread. Move it to thread2, then its thread affinity is thread2. *I want to change the gui* - what do you mean by this? The GUI must (with rare exceptions) be on the main thread. invokeMethod is another way of calling a slot of an object, usually on a different thread, but doesn't require connecting an object with a signal.

Comment: when I create a new widget I get the error: widgets must be created in the gui thread. I tried to use moveToThread(qApp->thread()) before I create the new widget but I still get the error.

Comment: Then I suggest starting a new question with examples of your code. You can read about how to create a good example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Each `QObject` **tree** can be assigned to a specified thread. `moveToThread` means move tree of objects (for given root object) to that thread.

That doesn't mean that that all code of the `QObject` is assigned to that thread. It means that any slot invoked by queued connection  (not direct connection) will be invoked in given thread. Read carefully documentation of [QObject::connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) and [Qt::ConnectionType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Except for `Qt::DirectConnection`, all connections use the owning thread of the receiving object to deliver the signal. All arguments are packed and sent to the receiver's event queue. When the receiving thread's event loop gains control it will unpack the arguments and invoke the slot.

Note that I wrote above about a tree of objects. You can't move an object to a different thread if it has a parent.  And you can't reparent an object to one that belongs in a different thread.

By default objects are assigned to thread which created them (if they do not have a parent). So it doesn't have to be main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread a,b,c;
a created b,  b created c;
connect(a, &QThread::finished, a, &QObject::deleteLater);
connect(b, &QThread::finished, b, &QObject::deleteLater);
connect(c, &QThread::finished, c, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

I do some experiment, found that if b had finished faster than c, c would not be deleted; But can do that:
    b->moveObject(a);   //then b would be deleted again.